# Who owned the starship that abandoned Rey on Jakku in her vision?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

When Rey was left on Jakku, she faintly remembers seeing a starship leave Jakku.

We're given a little glimpse of the Starship in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*.

**Who owned that Starship?**

As in, was it a First Order / Empire Starship or a "good guys" Starship?

---

<sup>Obviously this would be a huge clue into who left her there (maybe), but I do understand that there may not be an answer for it at this time.</sup>

Comment: I downvoted because (1) there is no way to know until the next movies come out and [it was decided that future works questions are off topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/530/should-questions-asking-about-the-future-of-a-franchise-series-or-literary-wor), (2) clearly no one knows except the people directly invovled, assuming they've even decided (either way, the answer is intentionally left out), and (3) someone with 10K rep should know better than to ask questions about unanswerable info.

Comment: @calccrypto I wouldn't say future-works questions are off-topic; the intention is [to put them on hold temporarily, with the intention of re-opening them later](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Comment: @JasonBaker I have no problem voting to reopen this later on, but for now, its not a particularly useful question other than the fact that its asking about a detail that the filmmakers kept secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ship was called the ***Bestoon Legacy***. It was, we learn in *Rise of Skywalker*, owned by a Sith loyalist named Ochi. The film's [Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) identifies it as a **Subpro Corporation Model WTK-85A interstellar transport**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question!

Answer (score 4):

We don't know *anything* about that ship yet.

- Novelizations don't say anything at all
- WGA script just says:

  ```
    little girl. Rey as a child. She is sobbing, hysterical.
    Unkar Plutt's meaty hand holds her thin arm. She is on Jakku,
    watching a starship fly into the sky, abandoning her.
    YOUNG GIRL
    No, come back!
    (CONTINUED)
    CONTINUED:
    UNKAR PLUTT
    Quiet, girl!
    The ship flies towards the desert sun, which is strangely
    eclipsed, as if being eaten by darkness. Rey looks around her to see she is..
  ```
- Available stills do NOT help much, but it sure as hell doesn't look like Falcon. Or anything else too familiar.

  [image] [image] [image] [image]