# Is Rey's vision accurate?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

In episode 7, Rey has a vision when she encounters Luke's lightsaber. I didn't watch it frame by frame, but I thought part of it included Kylo Ren in a mask, forcing someone to kneel. I interpreted it as the destruction of the Jedi temple, and Ren making the final break from Luke.

However in episode 8, we are treated to several flashbacks of the event, which appear to be visually different from Rey's vision.

Does Rey's vision in episode 8 include the destruction of the Jedi Temple?

Comment: *"Full of crap, Force Visions are"* - Yoda.

Comment: I'm not sure that part of the vision is the destruction of the temple.  There's an implication that the Knights of Ren made a pilgrimage to Endor to retrieve a sacred relic: the crushed and burnt mask of Darth Vader that we saw in Ren's chambers.  This part of Rey's vision could have been on the Forest Moon of Endor.

Comment: Not everything from those visions are from the destruction of the temple. We do see a confirmation that the scene with Luke kneeling with one hand on R2 has the temple fully burning in the background; but as has been identified in other answers Kylo's saber is not his iconic red one. In addition, it is unlikely that immediately after he burns the temple he would have found a mask and been surrounded by what looks like the Knights of Ren. That scene is likely from some time later on after he escaped the planet and formed/joined the Knights of Ren.

Comment: Related: [What were all those visions Rey saw?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111978/976)

Comment: Out of universe: The Last Jedi was mostly written by Rian Johnson before he watched The Force Awakens.

Comment: @Stumbler that fact doesn't make much sense; people who watched the movie didn't understand the content of the visions, as they were presented very fast. Meanwhile Johnson's script apparently had the major characters and plot points already-- Hux, Ren, Rey, etc. Han dead, Snoke controlling. It seems difficult to have written the script without knowing what had happened in Ep. VII.

Comment: @user151841 to be precise he had access to the dailies and overall structure of TFA's plot, but he wrote TLJ long before TFA was released

"When I was writing [the script] I was watching the dailies [from Force Awakens]. I’m really grateful the timing worked like that both so I could see Daisy, John, Adam, and Oscar in their roles, but I’m really thankful I wrote it before the movie came out."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is we have no context for the visions. Let's revisit it (starts about 0:42)

So we have

- Bespin? Star Wars corridors all look the same after a while. That does the twisty morph to...
- Luke sitting by R2D2 in front of a fire, as it starts to rain (seems to deliberately match up with the burning of the Jedi Temple [as seen in Luke's flashback in TLJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2VOo.jpg))
- We see some guy holding a staff who gets skewered by Kylo Ren. In the rain. It not clear if this connects to the burning of the Temple.
- Young Rey watching a transport leave, and yelling for it to come back
- A brief homage to [2001: A Space Odyssey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ou6JNQwPWE0) ("My god, it's full of StarKiller Base!")
- Obi-Wan Kenobi saying "Rey?"
- The scene in the woods at the end of TFA where she confronts Kylo Ren

TLJ adds *some* context (like why Ben turned), but you'll note that it was intentionally vague on details (who burned the temple? How long was Luke out? How did Snoke get into the picture?). But, most importantly, these are *flashbacks* of what actually happened, as opposed to a Force vision.

None of what's in Rey's vision is mutually exclusive of what we learned in TLJ.

Comment: I can't find the exact text for it right now but watching this scene with close captioning on reveals more. In addition to Obi-Wan saying her name both Obi-Wan and Yoda each speak around 3 or 4 lines each; including I believe Obi-Wan's last line to her was something like "This is the beginning of your path" or something similar

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

- Yes, her vision did... skip to the all bold paragraph to read my quick description and thoughts...
- First a recap of the vision.
- The only part of Rey's vision that showed the burning of the temple was where we see Luke on his knees next to R2
- Everything else from her vision is either before or after that.
- The vision is from the Jedi to Rey

**A recap of the actual vision:**

- Even before she touches the saber the 'visions' have already started. That is what draws her to the saber to begin with. They actually start at about 64 minutes into the movie. As she is standing in the bar and walking down the stairs we hear the CC discloses that we can her a young Rey screaming "NO!" and "NO, come back!" and etc.
- Almost two minutes later she finally touches the saber and the 'full on visions' begin. (I think it is also interesting how the sound we hear is a saber activating, but it never actually does.)
- So then she is 'transported' to some hallway and we hear young Rey again and we hear Yoda say "Its energy ... surrounds us ..."
- **Then she is lying on her stomach on the ground outside and she sees Luke kneeling next to R2. Yoda continues "...and binds us..." (Also not that there is the orange glow reflecting similar to a fire in front of them and it is snowing)**
- Then we hear a saber ignite and Rey turns to see Kylo stab someone through the back with his signature red saber. We hear Obi-Wan for the first time say "The force will be..." and Kylo turns his attention to Rey and begins to advance towards her. (Note that now Kylo is in his mask with the red saber, has some others around him [possibly the Knights of Ren] and it is now raining [therefore these events are not at the same time as the previous vision since it doesn't go from snow to rain in a blink] and we are safe to assume that since Kylo became 'mini-vader' after burning the temple these raining events are some time after)
- Then Rey turns to see her young self [they have the same hair style too] screaming again on Jakku with Unkar telling her "Quiet Girl" as we see what we assume is her parents leaving the planet in some ship.
- Then the sun in the distance turns into a slit with some bright red light emitting from it and we hear Obi-Wan say "Rey?" and she turns and starts running in some woods straight into Kylo.
- Then she falls backwards and back into Maz's basement and we hear Obi-Wan say "These are your first steps" and the vision ends. From the start of the full on vision to its end is about a minute. It goes from about 64 minutes to about 67 minutes in full.

**Explanation of the vision as I see it**

Admittedly I could be wrong, but this vision is from the Jedi to Rey to let her know she is key to their future and kind of cluing her on to both some things she has forgotten and things she needs to know. (I also like to think she might be getting some 'emotional transferrance' because some of the flashes mean very little to her, but feeling some emotion would at least let her know how she should feel... that is of course speculation however)

In chronological order:

First there is Rey being left on the planet as a child. She thinks that her parents are coming back for her, but the Jedi remind her that they left the planet without her. No matter where they are (alive or dead) they are not coming back. They ?sold? her to Unkar and left her. They want her to know it is time for her to move on.

Next there is Luke kneeling next to R2. This is letting her know that the guy with the mechanical hand is important. (Like I said, I like to think she is getting the feeling of his pain from this as well; maybe the book would say one way or the other if there is one...)

Then we see Kylo and ?his Knights? killing people with a bunch of dead people around them. It is also hard to make out but it looked to me like one the ?Knights? in the background had a red tube shaped weapon in his hand? I'm not sure what the Knights if Ren primarily used, but ... (i.e. They want Rey to know he is bad business)

Then we see Rey come face to face with Kylo in what looks like the forest where they have their first battle. I also believe that shrinking and red phasing sun is indicative of the sun being drained to power the first order weapon. (The Jedi possibly want Rey to recognize this situation she will soon find her self in.)

The only thing left is the first vision of the hallway and I have no clue where that fits in. I like to think that will come in somewhere down the line...

I know this explains more than you asked, but I thought the extra details might interest you...